# Child div goin out of parent div

Tags: html, css

The parent .container (pink) div does not expand vertically as per the content of the child div .red  Because of which, the .red div flows out of the .content div vertically down!

I tried correcting this by setting the height of the content div to "auto" from "100%", but when I do that, both the .top and the .container div disappears completely. Why is that?? Whats the best solution without including "overflow"

Please see the screenshots :

[image: Screenshot]

CSS

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
margin: 0px;
height: 100%;

}



.container {
width: auto;
float: none;
width: auto;
max-width: auto;
position: relative;
background-color: rgba(216,86,112,0.5);
height: 100%;
margin-top: auto;
margin-right: 5%;
margin-left: 5%;
display: block;
}




.top {
width: 100%;
background-color: rgba(204,51,0,1);
height: 10%;
position: relative;
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

.left {
float: left;
height: auto;
width: 32.33%;
background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
margin-left: auto;
}

.center {
float: left;
height: auto;
width: 32.33%;
background-color: rgba(0,255,0,1);
margin-left: 1.5%;
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
}

.right {
float: right;
height: auto;
width: 32.33%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">

<div class="top">
</div>

<div class="left">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a 
libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a 
libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a 
libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a 
libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a 
libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a 
libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a 
libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a 
libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
</div>

<div class="center">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a   
libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.
</div>

<div class="right">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula quis 
dolor sed euismod. Fusce id tellus est. Nam eu rutrum urna. Donec mattis a 
libero faucibus euismod. Suspendisse iaculis placerat sapien in ultrices.

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a clearfix class to your container and remove the `height:100%` in the css of the `container`

Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qpc0Lfjj/)

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this "clear" div after your "right" div and before closing container div.

```
<div style="clear: both ;" ></div>
```

Comment: added. did not made any difference. could you show it in jsfiddle using my above posted code?

Answer (score 0):

how about delete this :

> float: none;

on your `.container`

and i think u dont need any `position: relative` at all.

Comment: removed `float: none` and `position: relative` in the .container . made no difference

Comment: remove `position: relative` not just in .container, remove on .top .left .center and .right too.